# D3.js Donut transition

Tags: d3.js, transition, updates, donut-chart

I am working on a d3 donut and am stuck on how to update the donut value where the value will flow back if for instance you change the value from 42 to 17.
I can remove the svg, but then it rewrites the new value (17) from the zero position.

I would like it to flow backwards from 42 say to 17.

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(dataset.lower))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "color" + i })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial values
```

here is a link to my jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/yr595n96/

and I would love any help you could offer.

Thanks

Comment: your 'next' button click doesnt do/call anything ? :/ what do you want it to do ?

Comment: As per the comment in it, I want to be able to change the value of the donut from 42 to say 17 but that the red part of the donut should flow(transition) back to a value of 17. I hope that is clear. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: ahh i see, when calling it again like so : http://jsfiddle.net/yr595n96/1/, it creates a new 'donut'. you have to call your click inside the code where you draw the arc, ill have a look :)

Comment: Exactly, that is what I was doing. and if I use the remove() function, it works fine but the red disappears and starts from 0 again. I want it to go from 42 back to 17 if possible. Thanks

Comment: yeah i get you, transition between both without removing anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres you're new button click :

```
$("#next").click(function () {
    percent = 17;
    var progress = 0;
    var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        var randNumber = Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1) + 0;
        //path = path.data(pie(calcPercent(17))); // update the data << change this
        path = path.data(pie(calcPercent(randNumber)));
        path.transition().duration(duration).attrTween("d", function (a) {
            // Store the displayed angles in _current.
            // Then, interpolate from _current to the new angles.
            // During the transition, _current is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
            var i  = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, randNumber)
            this._current = i(0);
            return function(t) {
                text.text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
                return arc(i(t));
            };
        }); // redraw the arcs
    }, 100);
});
```

Notice on line '8':

```
path = path.data(pie(calcPercent(randNumber)));
```

You need to pass new data for it to transition to. I have used a random number here just to show you any number works. I made a variable for this and passed it to both the 'path' and the text : 'i2' > d3.interpolate.

You can always just change it to 17 to suit what you asked for :)

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yr595n96/3/

Comment: notice the text starts at 0 again and not at the last value. You can change this in the 'var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, randNumber)' just change 'progress' to current value. may have to create a boolean to check if its the first time you have clicked. if it is start from 0, if not start from last number :)